# "Invalid iterator range" while inserting initializer_list to an std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This code compiles and runs fine *as expected* on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Nj9r6J):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::wstring> strVec;
    strVec.insert(strVec.end(), { L"black", L"white", L"red" });
    strVec.insert(strVec.end(), { L"blue", L"green" }); // STL exception

    for (auto &i : strVec) {
        std::wcout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, fails with **"invalid iterator range"** in MSVC (Visual Studio 2013).. Any insight?

BTW, inserting more elements works, e.g. on the second insert, this works in MSVC:

```
strVec.insert( strVec.end(), { L"blue", L"green", L"yellow" } );
```

Related to capacity/size and invalidating some iterators? But second `insert` requests new iterator `end()`, which must be valid, right? Or... it's actually about initializer list?

*Note:* Not looking for workarounds here (tons of them) - just trying to figure out whether this is MSVC-specific bug or something legit wrong is going on...

Comment: If you want to add to the end, just use `push_back()`. Or, for the code above, just initialize it: `std::vector<std::wstring> strVec { L"black", L"white", L"red", L"blue", L"green"};`

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  If I run the same code on MSVS 2015 in release or debug mode it works as expected.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - thanks, but not related to the question

Comment: @OlegShirokikh: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: VS12 initializer lists are broken in many ways. Use with caution. Upgrade to VC14 or VC15 preview if possible.

Comment: I tried this with GCC, clang (various versions of both), and the MS online compiler at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net.   It worked fine on all of them.  So I suspect VS 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS 2013 has selected the overload `vector<T>::insert(const_iterator, const T&)`, constructing `wstring` from a pair of pointers `const wchar*, const wchar*` interpreted as the start and end of a range of characters; note that a wide string literal decays to a `const wchar*` pointer. This is why the problem only occurs when you try to insert precisely 2 elements.

Here's the call stack:

```
msvcp120d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line) Line 15 C++
Project1.exe!std::_Debug_range2<wchar_t const *>(const wchar_t * _First, const wchar_t * _Last, const wchar_t * _File, unsigned int _Line, std::random_access_iterator_tag __formal) Line 576   C++
Project1.exe!std::_Debug_range<wchar_t const *>(const wchar_t * _First, const wchar_t * _Last, const wchar_t * _File, unsigned int _Line) Line 584  C++
Project1.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >(const wchar_t * _First, const wchar_t * _Last) Line 860    C++
Project1.exe!main() Line 9  C++
```

VS 2013 is erroneous, because [**[over.ics.rank]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank):

> 3 - [...]
>
> - List-initialization sequence `L1` is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence `L2` if:
>
>   - `L1` converts to `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and `L2` does not [...]

This is fixed in VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this happens because when you write `{ L"blue", L"green" }` compiler use them as two pointers to construct value (`std::wstring`) and pass it into next `std::vector::insert` overloading:

```
insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value );
```

So it's likely that running from pointer `L"blue"` to `L"green"` ends somewhere where program has no permission to read, or it's check that first pointer is less than second and throw exception when they not.

Comment: Hm... This is interesting, and definitely possible.. I've seen before some mess happening with 2-element init-lists and picking the right f-n signature (two args or init_list)

Comment: Idea is from CppCon 2015, [C++ WAT](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/e9a15f33c32b17a7bd9d1386f1b282f8e35cfcf7/Lightning%20Talks%20and%20Lunch%20Sessions/C++%20WAT/C++%20WAT%20-%20Piotr%20Padlewski%20-%20CppCon%202015.pdf) by Piotr Padlewski: slides 17-20 - "braces are evil".